# Issue with Rails namespace Routing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

My issue is pretty simple and I think can be easily resolved using Restful Style, but i just want to do it in non-restful style.

```
# Controller
class Admin::SocialFeedsController < ApplicationController
...
end

# Rotues
namespace :admin do
  resources :social_feeds do
  collection do
    post 'create'
    get 'index'
    ...
    end
  end
end

<form action="/admin/social_feeds/create" method="post">
...
</form>
```

It want to map `social_feeds` action on Admin controller rather than the `Admin::SocialFeedsController`'s create action.

I dont want to use Rails Form Helpers here.

Thanks

Comment: @Syed. Thanks for editing, i just missed it in hurry.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Rotues
namespace :admin do
  resources :social_feeds
end
```

I'm assuming you want /admin/social_feeds URLs to work?

Comment: yes, i have tried this but still the same error. Putting the error in next comment.

Comment: http://local.testproject.com/admin/social_feeds/create


   ERROR:: AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'social_feeds' could not be found for AdminController)

Comment: What does your AdminController look like?  Does `rake routes` route the URL correctly?